# How to make every other div a different color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm stuck with some code which I would like the bg color to be alternated to a color on .itemrow of #F8F8F8

Here's the paste bin:
http://pastebin.com/mgHYzJAd

```
.itemrow {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
```

and the project page if you wanted to see it:
http://paolor.co.uk/projects/grubrun/menu.php

I've tried to do some research and nth-child(odd) has come up a few times but it's not something I've ever come across before in the 3 months I've been doing front end.

Any help is appreciated  and thank you in advance! :o)
Paolo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more flexibility, use a multiplier:

```
.itemrow:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
```

which can allow you to do this:

```
.itemrow:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k37m1yak/
Browser Support: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Answer (score 8):

What about:

```
.itemrow:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
```

Instead of `even` you could use `odd` too. It's a surprise to me that you haven't found it before. It's been around quite a while and is supported at least since IE9, and I think even from IE7. Then again, you don't need it that often. I think alternating backgrounds are the only purpose I've seen it used for so far.

Answer (score 4):

`nth-child(odd)` works for me. Have you tried:

```css
.itemrow:nth-child(odd) {
  /* your styles here */
}
```